# trying to replace a div with jquery slideDown click method

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to replace a div with another one once an element has been clicked, but I cant seem to get it working. I have included the HTML and jquery code below. The element which is trying to slide in has a css property of display: none.

HTML:

```
<div class="meal-details">
                        <h4>heading</h4>

                        <h5 class="optiontabs meal-description">DESCRIPTION</h5>
                        <h5 class="optiontabs nutrition-description">NUTRITIONAL INFO</h5>

                        <div class="nutrition-breakdown">

                        <p>Text one</p>

                        </div>

                        <div class="meal-breakdown">

                        <p>Text two</p>

                        </div>

                </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".nutrition-description").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".nutrition-breakdown").slideDown("fast");
    });
```

Can anyone see what is preventing it from sliding down? All help of course is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reason your code isn't working because you are using .find() method to find a container "nutrition-breakdown" inside "nutrition-description", which is not correct, "nutrition-breakdown" is actually a sibling of "nutrition-description"

**Kindly use below code to fit you requirement.**

```
$(".nutrition-description").click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideDown("fast");//change
```

});

If you dont need animation then better tp use .show() instead of slideDown().

Answer (score 1):

use `$(this).nextAll(".nutrition-breakdown")` to get the div with class .nutrition-breakdown that comes after `.nutrition-breakdown`.

```js
$(".nutrition-description").click(function(){
$(this).nextAll(".nutrition-breakdown").slideDown("fast");
});
```

```css
.nutrition-breakdown{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="meal-details">
                    <h4>heading</h4>

                    <h5 class="optiontabs meal-description">DESCRIPTION</h5>
                    <h5 class="optiontabs nutrition-description">NUTRITIONAL INFO</h5>

                    <div class="nutrition-breakdown">

                    <p>Text one</p>

                    </div>

                    <div class="meal-breakdown">

                    <p>Text two</p>

                    </div>

            </div>
```